# How can I clean white burn marks in the center of my glass top burner?

Tags: cleaning

I have this glass top burner for almost 5 years. It was fine until I cooked food in Aluminum Pot and Aluminum frying pan... the base of these pots leaft white marks on the glass. It looks like part of the glass now. I tried Baking Soda, Cerama Bryte, Soap but no results. How can I get rid of them pr will never will?

Answer (score 3):

I've heard of people having luck using a razor blade (like one for scraping paint from a window). Just be careful, as the glass could probably scratch easily.

Answer (score 1):

My parents have had good luck with a [steam cleaner.](http://www.canadiantire.ca/AST/browse/Green/HealthyHomeGarden/HouseholdCleaningProducts/PRD~0436256P/Shark+Steam+Blaster.jsp?locale=en) (Disclaimer: I am not endorsing this particular product, just linking so you know what I am referring to.) They use cerama bryte for standard cleaning and the steam cleaner for the stubborn stains.

Answer (score 0):

Use a mild abrasive compound like a copper metal polish. It will remove a minute trace of glass, but should not leave any visible marks if used correctly

The "Brasso" brand works for me